# How to join empty data to valued data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a following table  :

```
declare @Fromdate date;
declare @ToDate date;
set @Fromdate='2016-01-01'
set @ToDate='2016-01-11'

SELECT 
    MTime, CDate, MNAME, 
    tblCowMilk.MemNo,
    ISNULL(Liters, 0.0) as Litres, 
    ISNULL(FAT, 0.0) as FAT, 
    ISNULL(SNF, 0.0) as SNF,
    ISNULL(MRate, 0.0) as MRate, 
    ISNULL(Amount, 0.0) as Amount,
    SUM(Liters) as Total_Litres,
    SUM(Amount) as Total_Amount 
FROM 
    tblCowMilk 
INNER JOIN 
    TBLMEMBERS ON tblCowMilk.MemNo = TBLMEMBERS.MNO 
WHERE
    CDate between @FromDate and @ToDate 
    AND MType = 'C' 
    AND MemNo = 52
GROUP BY 
    MTime, CDate, MNAME, tblCowMilk.MemNo, Liters, FAT, SNF, Amount, MRate
```

[Table 1 Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UBt5.png)

Query #2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MTime, CDATE, 
    NULL AS MNAME, NULL AS MemNo,
    NULL as Litres, NULL as FAT,
    NULL AS SNF, NULL as MRate,
    NULL as Amount, NULL as Total_Litres,
    NULL as Total_Amount 
FROM 
    tblCowMilk 
--INNER JOIN TBLMEMBERS ON tblCowMilk.MemNo = TBLMEMBERS.MNO 
WHERE
    CDate between @FromDate and @ToDate 
    AND MType = 'C' 
GROUP BY 
    cdATE, MTIME
```

[Table 2 Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXCj9.png)

I want to join this two tables and getting the following result:

- if table1 has a row values it will replace the Table2 null values
- otherwise return empty row values
- I want result like second table format (11 days are fixed).if record is there in first table then replace corresponding position second table for example following way:

  E   2016-01-01  SHANMUGAM   52  1.900   3.0 7.8 23.04   43.78   1.900   43.78
  E   2016-01-02  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
  E   2016-01-03  SHANMUGAM   52  3.000   4.0 8.5 27.15   81.45   3.000   81.45
  E   2016-01-04  SHANMUGAM   52  4.000   3.9 8.4 26.70   106.80  4.000   106.80
  E   2016-01-05  SHANMUGAM   52  4.300   4.4 8.2 27.37   117.69  4.300   117.69
  E   2016-01-06  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
  E   2016-01-07  SHANMUGAM   52  7.000   4.1 8.2 26.70   186.90  7.000   186.90
  E   2016-01-08  SHANMUGAM   52  3.000   4.1 8.2 26.70   80.10   3.000   80.10
  E   2016-01-09  SHANMUGAM   52  3.000   4.0 8.0 26.03   78.09   3.000   78.09
  E   2016-01-10  SHANMUGAM   52  3.000   3.9 8.1 26.03   78.09   3.000   78.09
  E   2016-01-11  SHANMUGAM   52  24.000  8.0 8.0 34.99   839.76  24.000  839.76
  M   2016-01-01  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
  M   2016-01-02  SHANMUGAM   52  7.000   4.1 8.2 26.70   186.90  7.000   186.90
  M   2016-01-03  SHANMUGAM   52  4.000   4.0 8.2 26.48   105.92  4.000   105.92
  M   2016-01-04  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
  M   2016-01-05  SHANMUGAM   52  1.000   8.0 8.0 34.99   34.99   1.000   34.99
  M   2016-01-06  SHANMUGAM   52  28.000  4.1 8.0 26.25   735.00  28.000  735.00
  M   2016-01-07  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
  M   2016-01-08  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
  M   2016-01-09  SHANMUGAM   52  31.000  4.0 8.0 26.03   806.93  31.000  806.93
  M   2016-01-10  SHANMUGAM   52  3.000   3.3 7.8 23.71   71.13   3.000   71.13
  M   2016-01-11  SHANMUGAM   52  1.000   7.0 7.8 32.00   32.00   1.000   32.00

Comment: change inner to LEFT and if mtype is on tblMembers move it to the join as additional critier or the left join will be as if it was an inner join

Comment: change inner to LEFT and if mtype is on tblMembers move it to the join as additional criteria or the left join will be as if it was an inner join. and use coalesce() to force the engine to pick the first non-null value in a series... `Coalesce(tblMembers.liters, tblCowMilk.liters)`

Answer (score 1):

Table 2 query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MTime,CDATE,NULL AS MNAME,NULL AS MemNo,NULL as Litres
     , NULL as FAT,NULL AS SNF,NULL as MRate, NULL  as Amount
     , NULL as Total_Litres, NULL as Total_Amount 
FROM tblCowMilk 
LEFT JOIN TBLMEMBERS 
   ON tblCowMilk.MemNo = TBLMEMBERS.MNO 
  and MType='C' 
where CDate between @FromDate and @ToDate 
GROUP BY cdATE,MTIME
```

now to force the system to pick the first non-null value in a series simply use `coalesce()` on the values you want to use..

so perhaps...  `coalesce(tblmembers.litres, tblCowMil.litres,0)` for one example.  If members.litres isn't empty use it, otherwise use tblcowmilk.litres if it's not empty, otherwise put 0

I'll let you do them all as I'm not sure which ones match in each table.

When you want all results from one table and only those that match from another you need to use OUTER joins.

- LEFT JOIN  - Include only those records on in the first table and those matching in second.
- RIGHT JOIN - Include only those records on the 2nd table and only those matching from the first.
- FULL OUTER  - Include all records from all tables even if no match is found.

If you think about what the database engine does behind the scenes the need for moving criteria to the join will make sense.

1st the engine has to produce a combined records set

so if we have tables

```
A      B
ID     AID Property
1      1   A  
2      2   B
3
```

and we join these tables using a left join

```
Select * from A LEFT JOIN B on A.ID = B.AID 

AID  BAID   Property
1    1      A
2    2      B
3
```

Now if we apply a limit on property..

```
Select * from A LEFT JOIN B on A.ID = B.AID  where B.Property = 'A'

AID  BAID   Property
1    1      A
```

Where did the record 3 go?  It's because NULL is neither = 'A' nor not equal to 'A' it's NULL.  So this in effect the same as an inner join.

So to get record we have to move limits on the table on the outer side (those records matching) to the join criteria so the limit is applied at the same time as the join.  Order of operation is to do the joins then the where clause.

```
Select * from A LEFT JOIN B on A.ID = B.AID  and B.Property = 'A'

AID  BAID   Property
1    1      A
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    --DECLARATION PART FOR TEMP TABLES


    Declare @t1 table 
      (
          t1_MTime varchar(100), t1_CDate Datetime,t1_MNAME varchar(500),
          t1_MemNo int,t1_Litres decimal(18,1),t1_FAT decimal(18,1),t1_SNF decimal(18,1),
          t1_MRate decimal(18,2),t1_Amount decimal(18,2),t1_Total_Litres decimal(18,2),
          t1_Total_Amount decimal(18,2)
      )  

     Declare @t2 table (
            t2_MTime varchar(100), t2_CDate Datetime,t2_MNAME varchar(500),
            t2_MemNo int,t2_Litres decimal(18,1),t2_FAT decimal(18,1),t2_SNF decimal(18,1),
            t2_MRate decimal(18,2),t2_Amount decimal(18,2),t2_Total_Litres decimal(18,2),
            t2_Total_Amount decimal(18,2)
      )   

declare @Fromdate date;
declare @ToDate date;

set @Fromdate='2016-04-01'
set @ToDate='2016-04-11'

DECLARE @MyDate date;
set @MyDate=@FromDate;

--INSERT THE RECORDS INTO TEMP TABLE VARIABLES
 insert into @t1 (t1_MTime,t1_CDate,t1_MNAME,t1_MemNo,t1_Litres,t1_FAT,t1_SNF,t1_MRate,t1_Amount,t1_Total_Litres,t1_Total_Amount )
    SELECT 
        MTime, CDate, MNAME, 
        tblCowMilk.MemNo,
        ISNULL(Liters, 0.0) as Litres, 
        ISNULL(FAT, 0.0) as FAT, 
        ISNULL(SNF, 0.0) as SNF,
        ISNULL(MRate, 0.0) as MRate, 
        ISNULL(Amount, 0.0) as Amount,
        SUM(Liters) as Total_Litres,
        SUM(Amount) as Total_Amount 
    FROM   tblCowMilk INNER JOIN 
        TBLMEMBERS ON tblCowMilk.MemNo = TBLMEMBERS.MNO 
    WHERE
        CDate between @FromDate and @ToDate 
        AND MType = 'C'  
GROUP BY 
    MTime, CDate, MNAME, tblCowMilk.MemNo, Liters, FAT, SNF, Amount, MRate 

    --select distinct t1_MemNo from @t1


--CREATE CURSOR FOR LOOPING THE DISTINCT MEMBER NO
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @MyField varchar(50);
BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
    select distinct t1_MemNo from @t1     

    OPEN @MyCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
    INTO @MyField

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
            --LOOP THE FROMDATE AND TODATE RECORDS in the temp table variable @t1
            WHILE @MyDate <= @ToDate
                BEGIN
                    --print @MyField 
                    --print @MyDate                              

                              --print @MyField                            
                              --if record exists on date and memNo and MTime then insert into @t2 temp table else insert 0 values
                             if exists (select 1 from @t1 where t1_MemNo=@MyField and t1_CDate=@MyDate and t1_MTime='M')
                                  begin
                                    insert into @t2 (t2_MTime,t2_CDate,t2_MNAME,t2_MemNo,t2_Litres,t2_FAT,t2_SNF,t2_MRate,t2_Amount,t2_Total_Litres,
                                    t2_Total_Amount) 
                                    select t1_MTime,t1_CDate,t1_MNAME,t1_MemNo,t1_Litres,t1_FAT,t1_SNF,t1_MRate,t1_Amount,t1_Total_Litres,
                                    t1_Total_Amount from @t1 where t1_MemNo=@MyField and t1_CDate=@MyDate and t1_MTime='M'
                                  end
                              else
                                  begin
                                    insert into @t2(t2_MTime,t2_CDate,t2_MNAME,t2_MemNo,t2_Litres,t2_FAT,t2_SNF,t2_MRate,t2_Amount,t2_Total_Litres,
                                    t2_Total_Amount) values ('M',@MyDate,'-NA-',@MyField,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
                                  end

                             if exists (select * from @t1 where t1_MemNo=@MyField and t1_CDate=@MyDate and t1_MTime='E')
                                  begin
                                    insert into @t2 (t2_MTime,t2_CDate,t2_MNAME,t2_MemNo,t2_Litres,t2_FAT,t2_SNF,t2_MRate,t2_Amount,t2_Total_Litres,
                                    t2_Total_Amount)

                                    select t1_MTime,t1_CDate,t1_MNAME,t1_MemNo,t1_Litres,t1_FAT,t1_SNF,t1_MRate,t1_Amount,t1_Total_Litres,
                                    t1_Total_Amount from @t1 where t1_MemNo=@MyField and t1_CDate=@MyDate and t1_MTime='E'
                                  end
                              else
                                  begin
                                    insert into @t2(t2_MTime,t2_CDate,t2_MNAME,t2_MemNo,t2_Litres,t2_FAT,t2_SNF,t2_MRate,t2_Amount,t2_Total_Litres,
                                    t2_Total_Amount) values ('E',@MyDate,'-NA-',@MyField,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
                                  end
                        --INCREMENT THE DATE UPTO TODATE
                        SET @MyDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @MyDate)  
            END --Date While Loop END
        --RESET THE @MyDate to Intial for Next Member
        set @MyDate=@FromDate;  
      FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
      INTO @MyField 
    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;

select * from @t2
```